# List all subdirectories of a folder with with an specified depth

Tags: linux, bash, centos

I want to list all  sub-directories of a folder which their depth is only 2. So far by looking at previous questions and users answers I come up to this code,

```
i=0                  
for directory in `find  ./input   -maxdepth 3   -type d -mindepth 2 `
   do
   arr[i]=$directory
   let "i += 1"
 echo $directory
done
```

I run this code in Fedora machine and it gave me correct answers, but when I run it in centOS, it is not working. Actually -maxdepth works but not -mindepth.

to be more specific in Fedora the output is like this:

-./input/ Staphylococcus/200

-./input/ Staphylococcus/50

-./input/ Staphylococcus/100

-./input/ Staphylococcus/150

-./input/Neisseria_meningitidis/200

-./input/Neisseria_meningitidis/50

-./input/Neisseria_meningitidis/100

-./input/Neisseria_meningitidis/150

which is my desire output and in in centOS the output contains these list as well as some other directories with longer depth.

Another interesting thing is when I run

./input -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2  -type d

in my command prompt screen it gives me  again correct answer, but not in bash file.

I am really confused whatever I searched I didn't find any alternative for mindepht flag.

Comment: trying to reproduce...

Comment: was not able to reproduce this, sorry. Which version of centOS are you using? what's the output of `find -version`?

Comment: what's the output when it doesn't run?

Comment: output of find -version? is : find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Eric B. Decker, James Youngman, and Kevin Dalley.
Built using GNU gnulib version e5573b1bad88bfabcda181b9e0125fb0c52b7d3b
Features enabled: D_TYPE O_NOFOLLOW(enabled) LEAF_OPTIMISATION SELINUX FTS() CBO(level=0)

Comment: 4.4.2 from 2007 is kinda old; mine's a 4.5.2 somewhen from 2012; maybe there's actually a bug in 4.4.2. This feels like it would be a good time to take your question, the bash file and open up a bug at savannah.gnu.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work but if for some reason it is not working then you can just use this glob pattern:

```
printf "%s\n" ./input/*/*/
```

`./input/*/*/` will match all 2 level deep directories inside `input` directory

Comment: Note the trailing slash: that limits the results to directories only

Comment: It is well tested command. Make sure you're using BASH. Also **doesn't work** is meaningless unless you provide all the details of the error.

Comment: sorry dude, there was another problem, my folder name was consisting of two names with _ between words, and it didn't work.